# Finding two specific numbers in huge arrays

Tags: java-7

I'm currently trying to solve an algorithm problem and due to being new to programming I feel like I won't be able to figure it out without some knowledge first. My intention is not to receive the answer to the problem but recommendations to process huge arrays in Java.

The problem is: you receive a number (3 > n < 200.000) and then receive a sorted array of numbers that has n length and then you receive another number (n2) (all the numbers can be hold by an int).

You have to find two numbers in the array that their sum will make n2-n.

You will always have a right answer and will always be two numbers.

Per example:
3
1 2 3
3
The answer would be 1 and 2 because 6 - 3 = 3;

My code works but it exceeds time and memory consumption. So I'm looking for someone to tell better ways to find those numbers than can also be applicable to improve my algorithm practices.

What I've done so far is to sum all the numbers in the array and obtain n2 - n; then create two indexes, the first 0 and the second (n2 - n) - 1; Then loop through while the first index is less than the second index. During the loop, performing a binary search of the first index and of the second index. If the binary search finds both numbers then return them as the answer.

```
public static BufferedReader br;
public static int numHechizos;
public static String line;
public static String[] split;
public static int damage;
public static int[] hechizos;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    numHechizos = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    while (numHechizos != 0){
        caso(numHechizos);
        numHechizos = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
}

public static void caso(int numHechizos) throws IOException {
    line = br.readLine();
    split = line.split(" ");
    damage = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    int sum = 0;
    hechizos = new int[numHechizos];
    for (int i = 0; i < numHechizos; i++) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
        hechizos[i] = num;
        sum += num;
    }

    int find = sum - damage;
    int n1 = 1; int n2 = find - 1;
    while (n1 < n2){
        int bn1 = Arrays.binarySearch(hechizos, n1);
        int bn2 = Arrays.binarySearch(hechizos, n2);

        if (bn1 > -1 && bn2 > -1){
            System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
            break;
        }
        n1++;
        n2--;
    }

    System.gc();
}
```

Comment: What does `n2` represent? `n^2`? (n to the 2nd power)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. n2 represents the second number.

Comment: n1 = 3;
int[] = {1, 2, 3}
n2 = 3;

expected output: 1, 2